# How do these cross site scripting fixes work?

Tags: c#, xss

I have code that supposedly has been cleaned of cross site scripting vulnerabilities.

Ex:

```
<%# Eval("Name") %> (<%# Eval(" FriendlyId") %>)
```

was modified to:

```
<%#: Eval("Name") %> (<%# Eval(" FriendlyId") %>)
```

and

```
<%= string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPlan.VisionPlan.PlanCategory) ? "-" : SelectedPlan.VisionPlan.PlanCategory %>
```

was modified to:

```
<%: string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPlan.VisionPlan.PlanCategory) ? "-" : SelectedPlan.VisionPlan.PlanCategory %>
```

How does simply adding those colons prevent a cross site scripting attack from occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%: >` is a new syntax for HTML encoding output introduced in ASP.NET 4. Without this syntax you would have to write

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode(Model.Content) %>
```

The same can be expressed using the new syntax in a more readable and consise manner:

```
<%: Model.Content %>
```

Scott Guthrie explains further details:

> The new `<%: %>` syntax provides a concise way to automatically HTML encode content and then render it as output.  It allows you to make your code a little less verbose, and to easily check/verify that you are always HTML encoding content throughout your site.  This can help protect your applications against cross-site script injection (XSS) and HTML injection attacks.

See **[New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2)** for more details.

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there a name for what that syntax is called other than the syntax you use to access variables in C#?